# how to horizontally and vertically center chart items in a grid box

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm already two hours on this, but couldn't find a solution yet

I have a couple of `li` items that together represent a chart in my `ul` grid container

I want this chart to be centralized so i tried to add those properties to my grid box

```
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
```

```css
#button-cash {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
  grid-auto-rows: 10vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  
}

li {
 width: 35px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: rgb(65, 171, 185);
}

#price-screen, #button-cash, #cash-in-drawer {
   background-color: rgb(159, 227, 236);
}
```

```html
 <ul id="button-cash">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
          
</ul>
```

but instead i got this result
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvdTg.png)

the chart being slightly away from the edge from my container

So I thought it would be smarter to make my grid container
`position: relative;`

while i added the following css to my  li chart

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
bottom: 50%;
transform(50%, -50%);
```

it worked but i got this  result instead
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAc37.png)
all the `li` fused into one single element while they were centralized

I believe the solution for this is quite simple but im not being able to find out what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a justify-content: center to make it center instead of justify- items. Let me know if this is what you mean

```css
#button-cash {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  
  
}

li {
 width: 35px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: rgb(65, 171, 185);
}

#price-screen, #button-cash, #cash-in-drawer {
   background-color: rgb(159, 227, 236);
}
```

```html
<ul id="button-cash">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
          
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually yeah, but I thought justify-content wouldnt really work because for me it was a exclusive flex property, because grid and flex cant be used in the same selector, also I noticed you took away the `grid-auto-rows`, was it causing some interference?

Comment: That is correct the grid auto rows are affecting your code as well and justify content works on your code.  glad this works for you.